# Error when Trying to Plot XY data in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to plot XY data from a .csv file in beamer (Overleaf). I am getting a lot of error codes, but the first one is shown below:

> LaTeX Error: \begin{axis} on input line 9 ended by
> \end{beamer@framepauses}.

I have created another smaller document to be able to post my complete code as shown below:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{KSU Header.png}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{KSU Footer.png}}

\definecolor{purpleheart}{rgb}{0.41, 0.21, 0.61}
\usecolortheme[named=purpleheart]{structure}
    
\title{Nonlinear Numerical Analysis of Non-Planar Rectangular Hollow Structural Section Connections}
\author{Latex User}
\date{}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2in]{KState Engineering Logo.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}[t,fragile]

\begin{wrapfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x label style={at=(.50,-0.1)},
    x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    y label style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=west},
    legend style={at={(.5,-0.65)},anchor= south, legend columns=1},
    ymin=0,ymax=70,
    xlabel = Local Displacement (in),
    every axis x label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel = Force (kip),
    every axis y label/.style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel},    
    xmin=0, xmax=40,
    xtick={0,0.02,...,0.2},,
x tick label style={rotate=45},
width=0.95\linewidth
]
\begin{scope}[
      every pin edge/.style={<-,>=latex, mark size=3pt},
      every pin/.append style={font=\large}]

\begin{filecontents}{Graph_Data.dat}
n   r     a        k 
1          100          100          100
2       95.721       98.645       98.738
4        82.31       93.497       93.295
8       56.667       63.901       63.838
16       46.536       52.572        53.31
32       45.399       53.421       53.318
\end{filecontents}

3-Percent Local Deformation Limit
\addlegendentry{3-Percent Local Deformation Limit}
\addplot[color = brown,dashed,thick] table [y=r, x=a]{Graph_Data.dat},
        \node[decoration=snake,coordinate,pin={[pin distance=1 in,pin edge={brown}]135:{45.4 kip, 3\% local $\delta$} } ]
            at (axis cs:0.12,45.4) {},
        \node[coordinate,pin={[pin distance=.5 in,pin edge={brown,thick}]45:{32.52 kip, 3\% $\delta$} } ]
            at (axis cs:0.12,48.35) {};           
            
\node[inner sep=0pt] (whitehead) at (axis cs:0.16,10)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{Thesis Presentation/Chapter 3 Images/Bird Beak/JPEGs/Abaqus Flexure Displacement.pdf}};

\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{T-Specimen Compression Results}
\label{CornerMaterial}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is where the error is shown:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please merge your codes fragments to one small, complete document, which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is. So far the first code fragment is not complete ... Help us to help you!

Comment: Hi Zarko! It may be user error, but when I tried to comment and add a longer code I went way over the character count, so I went back and edited my original post with a different, more complete, code. 

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: I seem to have solved this by removing \wrapfigure from the code

Comment: Yes, don't use wrap figure in beamer. The `columns` environment is normally the way to go.

Comment: Rmano, is there some way I can upvote, or "approve" your comment?

Comment: @Rmano Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz there are so many errors in the code...  wrong usage of wrapfigure, unbalanced braces, a filecontent in a fragile environment... lot of copied and pasted options overriding each other... I really would not know what to write here, modulo posting an unrelated example of using `columns`.

Comment: @Rmano OK, was worth a try :P